# Iterate through controls in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i have 9 `IBOutlets` for `imageView` named imageView1,imageView2,....

i have to assign first object of array to imageView1 & second object to imageView2,.....

Now my question is- is there any way to iterate through the property name

example-

```
 for(int i=0;i<[randomizedArray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *imageViewName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",@"imageView",i];
       imageViewName.image=[appDelegate.splittedImageArray ObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

that means it automatically assign value as

```
imageView1.image=[appDelegate.splittedImageArray ObjectAtIndex:i];
imageView2.image=[appDelegate.splittedImageArray ObjectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: take IBOutletCollection of UIImageView and iterate through array to assign images for each imageview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you could get to something like that without changing the IBOutlets would be this:

```
NSArray *imageViews = @[imageView1,imageView2,imageView3, ...];
for(int i=0; i<[randomizedArray count]; i++) {
    [[imageViews objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[appDelegate.splittedImageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

But there is a better solution - [`IBOutletCollection`](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/)

You can define a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imageViews;
```

And connect all of your imageViews like so:

[image]

Then you will have an array containing all of your `UIImageView`s, and you can use the above code without having to declare such an array manually...

Answer (score 0):

dont think it complexly. This is very simple. put tag for the imageviews like tag 1 for imageview1, 2 for imageview2 and so on. Then run a for loop and pick the object and assign to the array. Thats all.

Like assume you put tag from 1 to 7 (don't put duplicate tag or 0 for any of your views)

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int ii = 1; ii<=7; ii++){
    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ii];
    [arr addObject:imgView];
}
yourArray = arr;
[arr release];//if your array is a property otherwise no need to release.
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

use  `NSClassFromString`

```
 for(int i=0;i<[randomizedArray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *imageViewName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",@"imageView",i];
       Class theClass = NSClassFromString(imageViewName);

       theClass.image=[appDelegate.splittedImageArray ObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I have used to do this . Created the array of IBOutlets so you can iterate through it and assign the corresponding image.

```
for(int i=0;i<[randomizedArray count];i++)
 {
     UIImageView *imageView=[imageOutlets objectAtIndex:i];
     UIImage *image=[images objectAtIndex:i];
     imageView.image=image;
 }
```